# Lack of cached execution plans when using `IN` clause

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, query-performance

Microsoft's documentation on [Caching Mechanisms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293623.aspx) contains a description of Autoparameterization. As I understand it, Autoparameterization allows SQL Server (under certain circumstances) to use a previously cached execution plan for a query even if the specific parameters for that instance of the query are unique.

However, the documentation on that page states that "there are many query constructs that normally disallow autoparameterization". One of these constructs is the `IN` clause.

I have several queries in my application that use the `IN` clause. Each of these queries could have an arbitrary number of values in the `IN` clause. If I understand the documentation referenced above, then the execution plans for these queries will not be cached.

Questions:

1) Is there a recommended way to write these sorts of queries in order to bypass this limitation and take advantage of cached execution plans (other than using forced parameterization at a database level)?

2) How can I evaluate the impact that these queries are having on the overall performance of the database (e.g., how can I answer quantitatively whether or not it is worth my time to worry about the lack of cached execution plans)?

Thank you in advance for any insight you can provide.

Comment: Just brainstorming here... have you tried to replace the IN clause with an INNER JOIN to try and take advantage of cached plans? Assuming your queries are procedure based, you could test it with and without "WITH RECOMPILE"?

Comment: @scsimon Unfortunately the list of values provided to the IN clause is essentially arbitrary, which is why I'm using it instead of a JOIN. If I could, I would :)

Comment: [this is what i meant(http://rextester.com/EVY47167)], which of course will be dependent on your indexes.

Comment: In an Oracle world Imwould try to have a variable number of arguments split into some well known batches (1010 into 500+500+5+5). The splitting is most often needed anyway if the list can be large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Is there a recommended way to write these sorts of queries in order
>   to bypass this limitation and take advantage of cached execution plans
>   (other than using forced parameterization at a database level)?

Paul White explained it [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/09/sql-plan/rewriting-queries-improve-performance) with examples.

> 2) How can I evaluate the impact that these queries are having on the
>   overall performance of the database (e.g., how can I answer
>   quantitatively whether or not it is worth my time to worry about the
>   lack of cached execution plans)?

You need do some collection and aggregation for this one.

- Once you compare the performance of your rewrite as explained in Paul's article you know the difference (in io, cpu) for one call + time for recompilation.
- Multiply that by number of calls (of the changed query) in x period.
- Add those numbers for all the query you rewrite.
- Another approach is to benchmark you overall workload, make change to small number of queries and compare with baseline.
- If moving in the right direction make more changes (provided workload did not change),otherwise go back to starting point. Evaluate one by one.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. The blog post you linked is great; this is exactly the sort of info I was hoping to get. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that you found it useful.

Comment: Paul whites explanation is a good read, but how is it related to IN forced parameter binding and variable parameter number?

Comment: Agree with @eckes, I don't see anything related to the 1st question in the article